# Vertically center div inside Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="carousel" id="my-carousel">
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="text-center">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="text-center">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="text-center">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have the following script for normalizing the carousel:

```
function normalizeCarousel() {
  function normalize() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".carousel-item").each(function() {
      var currentHeight = $(this).height();
      if (currentHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = currentHeight;
      }
    });
    $("#my-carousel").css("height", maxHeight);
  };

  normalize();
  $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function() {
    normalize();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  normalizeCarousel();
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5boz16L/)

What I'm trying to do is vertically align each `text-center` div inside the `carousel-items`. I've tried using `flexbox` but couldn't manage to make it work!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is ought to do the trick

```
.carousel-item {
  display: table;
}
.text-center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the items are now displayed somewhere in the upper left corner and then they disappear.

Comment: @GeorgeR. what about now?

Comment: Nope, now the items are overlapped, and several items are shown in the same carousel slide.

Comment: I added one in the question description!

Answer (score 0):

with flexbox, use something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
/* Make the image fully responsive */
.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.text-center {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Indicators -->
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>

<!-- The slideshow -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<div class="text-center">Text Vertically Center Aligned</div>
<img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="text-center">Text Vertically Center Aligned</div>
<img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<div class="text-center">Text Vertically Center Aligned</div>
<img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
</div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I believe it has to do with the fact that flexbox overrides the hidden attribute that Bootstrap carousel is using.

Comment: please check my updated answer, let me know if you face any issue